# rst - csv table not working?

Tags: python, html-table, odoo, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I have this rst page:

```
=================================================
Transition records usage in leads & opportunities
=================================================

Transition record is a record that is created when one of the following
happens:

* Lead is converted to Opportunity.
* Opportunity stage is changed.
* Opportunity is won.
* Opportunity is lost.
* Opportunity goes from lost to active again.

Transition fields and mapping with general terms
================================================

.. csv-table:: Fields
   :header: "Key", "Type", "Label", "General Label", "Description"
   :widths: 15, 10, 30, 30, 50

   "id", "integer", "ID", "ID", "Transition record internal database ID"
   "create_date", "datetime", "Created On", "Created On", "When transition was created"
   "create_uid", "many2one", "Created By", "Created By", "Who created transition"
   "date_deadline", "date", "Expected Closing", "", "When opportunity is expected to be closed"
   "lead_id", "many2one", "Lead/Opportunity", "Lead/Opportunity", "Relation with lead or opportunity"
   "name", "char", "Opportunity Name", "Transformation Name", "Name name of opportunity"
   "user_id", "many2one", "Salesperson", "Owner", "Responsible user for opportunity"
   "team_id", "many2one", "Sales Channel", "Business Unit", "Sales Channel (Team) for this opportunity"
   "partner_id", "many2one", "Customer", "Account", "Customer for this opportunity"
   "throughput", "float", "Throughput", "Throughput", ""
   "prev_stage_id", "many2one", "Previous Stage", "Previous Stage", ""
   "next_stage_id", "many2one", "Next Stage", "Next Stage", ""
   "lost_reason", "many2one", "Lost Reason", "Lost Reason", ""
   "type", "selection", "Type", "Type", "Type of lead/opportunity. Either 'lead' or 'opportunity'"
   "description", "text", "Notes", "Description", "Information about opportunity"
```

When I try to build with `make html`, it fails with this error:

```
 File "/home/oerp/odoo11/source/documentation-user/_extensions/odoo/translator.py", line 311, in visit_title
    assert isinstance(parent, nodes.section), "expected a section node as parent to the title, found {}".format(parent)
AssertionError: expected a section node as parent to the title, found <table ids="id1"><title>Fields</title><tgroup cols="5"><colspec colwidth="15"/><colspec colwidth="10"/><colspec colwidth="30"/><colspec colwidth="30"/><colspec colwidth="50"/><thead><row><entry><paragraph>Key</paragraph></entry><entry><paragraph>Type</paragraph></entry><entry><paragraph>Label</paragraph></entry><entry><paragraph>General Label</paragraph></entry><entry><paragraph>Description</paragraph></entry></row></thead><tbody><row><entry><paragraph>id</paragraph></entry><entry><paragraph>integer</paragraph></entry><entry><paragraph>ID</paragraph></entry><entry><paragraph>ID</paragraph></entry><entry><paragraph>Transition record internal database ID</paragraph></entry></row><row><entry><paragraph>create_date</paragraph></entry><entry><paragraph>datetime</paragraph></entry><entry><paragraph>Created On</paragraph></entry><entry><paragraph>Created On</paragraph></entry><entry><paragraph>When transition was created</paragraph></entry></row><row><entry><paragraph>create_uid</paragraph></entry><entry><paragraph>many2one</paragraph></entry><entry><paragraph>Created By</paragraph></entry><entry><paragraph>Created By</paragraph></entry><entry><paragraph>Who created transition</paragraph></entry></row><row><entry><paragraph>date_deadline</paragraph></entry><entry><paragraph>date</paragraph></entry><entry><paragraph>Expected Closing</paragraph></entry><entry/><entry><paragraph>When opportunity is expected to be closed</paragraph></entry></row><row><entry><paragraph>lead_id</paragraph></entry><entry><paragraph>many2one</paragraph></entry><entry><paragraph>Lead/Opportunity</paragraph></entry><entry><paragraph>Lead/Opportunity</paragraph></entry><entry><paragraph>Relation with lead or opportunity</paragraph></entry></row><row><entry><paragraph>name</paragraph></entry><entry><paragraph>char</paragraph></entry><entry><paragraph>Opportunity Name</paragraph></entry><entry><paragraph>Transformation Name</paragraph></entry><entry><paragraph>Name name of opportunity</paragraph></entry></row><row><entry><paragraph>user_id</paragraph></entry><entry><paragraph>many2one</paragraph></entry><entry><paragraph>Salesperson</paragraph></entry><entry><paragraph>Owner</paragraph></entry><entry><paragraph>Responsible user for opportunity</paragraph></entry></row><row><entry><paragraph>team_id</paragraph></entry><entry><paragraph>many2one</paragraph></entry><entry><paragraph>Sales Channel</paragraph></entry><entry><paragraph>Business Unit</paragraph></entry><entry><paragraph>Sales Channel (Team) for this opportunity</paragraph></entry></row><row><entry><paragraph>partner_id</paragraph></entry><entry><paragraph>many2one</paragraph></entry><entry><paragraph>Customer</paragraph></entry><entry><paragraph>Account</paragraph></entry><entry><paragraph>Customer for this opportunity</paragraph></entry></row><row><entry><paragraph>throughput</paragraph></entry><entry><paragraph>float</paragraph></entry><entry><paragraph>Throughput</paragraph></entry><entry><paragraph>Throughput</paragraph></entry><entry/></row><row><entry><paragraph>prev_stage_id</paragraph></entry><entry><paragraph>many2one</paragraph></entry><entry><paragraph>Previous Stage</paragraph></entry><entry><paragraph>Previous Stage</paragraph></entry><entry/></row><row><entry><paragraph>next_stage_id</paragraph></entry><entry><paragraph>many2one</paragraph></entry><entry><paragraph>Next Stage</paragraph></entry><entry><paragraph>Next Stage</paragraph></entry><entry/></row><row><entry><paragraph>lost_reason</paragraph></entry><entry><paragraph>many2one</paragraph></entry><entry><paragraph>Lost Reason</paragraph></entry><entry><paragraph>Lost Reason</paragraph></entry><entry/></row><row><entry><paragraph>type</paragraph></entry><entry><paragraph>selection</paragraph></entry><entry><paragraph>Type</paragraph></entry><entry><paragraph>Type</paragraph></entry><entry><paragraph>Type of lead/opportunity. Either 'lead' or 'opportunity'</paragraph></entry></row><row><entry><paragraph>description</paragraph></entry><entry><paragraph>text</paragraph></entry><entry><paragraph>Notes</paragraph></entry><entry><paragraph>Description</paragraph></entry><entry><paragraph>Information about opportunity</paragraph></entry></row></tbody></tgroup></table>
The full traceback has been saved in /tmp/sphinx-err-Itc3Kc.log, if you want to report the issue to the developers.
Please also report this if it was a user error, so that a better error message can be provided next time.
A bug report can be filed in the tracker at <https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues>. Thanks!
Makefile:60: recipe for target 'html' failed
make: *** [html] Error 1
```

I thought maybe I made some mistake, but an example from documentation gives same error:

```
.. csv-table:: Frozen Delights!
   :header: "Treat", "Quantity", "Description"
   :widths: 15, 10, 30

   "Albatross", 2.99, "On a stick!"
   "Crunchy Frog", 1.49, "If we took the bones out, it wouldn't be
   crunchy, now would it?"
   "Gannet Ripple", 1.99, "On a stick!"
```

Is `csv-table` supposed to work?.. I also tried grid table, but it was very clunky and slow to write any table.

P.S. I'm using `Sphinx v1.3.6`

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the CSV table as far as I can tell. It works fine for me. The error comes from  /home/oerp/odoo11/source/documentation-user/_extensions/odoo‌​/translator.py. Is it the same as https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/11.0/doc/_extensions/odoo_ext/translator.py?

Comment: Yes I cloned repository today, so it should be the same. Maybe some kind of bug that prevents from parsing `csv-table`?

Comment: Does it make a difference if you remove the "odoo" extension from conf.py (https://github.com/odoo/documentation-user/blob/11.0/conf.py#L33) and rebuild the documentation?

Comment: Then it fails to generate anything. Would need tweak conf I guess to properly ignore that part.